# Проблема с GWT2.3 в IDEA10

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

Проект перестал компилироваться после перехода с GWT2.2 на GWT2.3. Проект создан с помощью IntelliJ IDEA 10. Не получается сгенерировать js-файл. В состав GWT2.3 входит новый jar-архив: validation-api-1.0.0.GA (два отдельный архива: в одном сорцы, в другом - class-файлы). Посла добавлении в структуру проекта, в Libraries, этих двух архивов, всё равно пишет ошибку, что

> No source code is available for type
> javax.validation.ConstraintViolation<t>;
> did you forget to inherit a required
> module?
>
> No source code is available for type
> javax.validation.ConstraintViolation<t>;
> did you forget to inherit a required
> module?
>
> No source code is available for type
> javax.validation.ConstraintViolation<t>;
> did you forget to inherit a required
> module?
>
> No source code is available for type
> javax.validation.TraversableResolver;
> did you forget to inherit a required
> module?
>
> No source code is available for type
> javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorFactory;
> did you forget to inherit a required
> module?
>
> No source code is available for type
> javax.validation.ValidatorFactory; did
> you forget to inherit a required
> module?

И так далее...

В общем, не находит то, что содержится в новом jar-архиве. Гугл находит только результаты, где люди вообще забывали добавить этот архив в проект.

Comment: компиляция через ант?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File -> Project Structure -> Libraries

Добавьте **оба** джарника, validation-api-1.0.0.GA и validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources, в раздел Classes. Вот так:

[image]

Или скачайте Idea 10.5. Там эта проблема исправлена :)

Comment: Я опытным путем так и сделал. Значит это баг в Идеи? Забавно.

Answer (score 0):

Может из-за депенденси модуля проблема? 
В либах у меня создана папка gwt, которая автоматом видится в депенденси модуля. Но если депенденси либы не видит ее все равно что нет.
Ну и в фасетах адрес новой версии ГВТ должен стоять.